# How can I sort the nodes of Sankey chart in rechart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sankey-diagram, recharts

I want to sort my nodes in Sankey chart. How can I do that?
For example, for the following data:

```
const data0 = {
  nodes: [
    { name: "L0" },
    { name: "L1" },
    { name: "L2" },
    { name: "L3" },
    { name: "L4" },
    { name: "R5" },
    { name: "R6" },
    { name: "R7" },
    { name: "R8" },
    { name: "R9" }
  ],
  links: [
    { source: 0, target: 5, value: 30 },
    { source: 1, target: 8, value: 99 },
    { source: 1, target: 7, value: 20 },
    { source: 1, target: 6, value: 15 },
    { source: 4, target: 5, value: 6 },
    { source: 2, target: 8, value: 30 },
    { source: 0, target: 6, value: 15 },
    { source: 2, target: 9, value: 11 },
    { source: 3, target: 9, value: 8 },
    { source: 3, target: 8, value: 23 },
    { source: 2, target: 5, value: 20 }
  ]
};
```

For this data, the Sankey chart will be as follows:
[image]
But I want to sort the nods on each side. I want nodes to be on each side in this way:
[image]
How can I do that?